# modify number in string php separated by comma

Tags: php

I have a string of numbers. The numbers appear in sets of three. I would like to change the second number in the set depending on the first number in the set.

This is my code so far.

```
$value='1 0 0,4 2 0,1 20 0,3 0 0,2 0 0,2 0 0,3 0 0,4 0 0,4 0 0,3 0 0,3 0 0,4 0 0,4 0 0,1 0 0,4 0 0,2 0 0,1 0 0,2 0 0,0 0 0,0 0 0,0 0 0,0 0 0,0 0 0,0 0 0,10 20 0,15 20 0,0 0 0,0 0 0,11 20 0,23 10 0,0 0 0,0 0 0,27 7 0,0 0 0,0 0 0,0 0 0,0 0 0,0 0 0,16 1 0,0 0 0';
$resouces_array=explode(',', $value);

foreach ($resouces_array as $key=> $value)
{
    $first_number  =substr($value,0,2);
    $second_number   = explode(' ', $value);

    // Part where I specify what the second number should be depending on the first number.
    if($first_number == 23)
    {
        $second_number[1]= 50;
    }

    //$first_parts= explode(' ', $value);
    $string_valo= implode(' ' ,$second_number);
    $after_spli=str_pad($string_valo, 6,',');
    echo $after_spli;
}
```

I want the output to be like this.

```
1 0 0,4 2 0,1 20 0,3 0 0,2 0 0,2 0 0,3 0 0,4 0 0,4 0 0,3 0 0,3 0 0,4 0 0,4 0 0,1 0 0,4 0 0,2 0 0,1 0 0,2 0 0,0 0 0,0 0 0,0 0 0,0 0 0,0 0 0,0 0 0,10 20 0,15 20 0,0 0 0,0 0 0,11 20 0,23 50 0,0 0 0,0 0 0,27 7 0,0 0 0,0 0 0,0 0 0,0 0 0,0 0 0,16 1 0,0 0 0';
```

But my code produces this.

```
1 0 0,4 2 0,1 20 03 0 0,2 0 0,2 0 0,3 0 0,4 0 0,4 0 0,3 0 0,3 0 0,4 0 0,4 0 0,1 0 0,4 0 0,2 0 0,1 0 0,2 0 0,0 0 0,0 0 0,0 0 0,0 0 0,0 0 0,0 0 0,10 20 015 20 00 0 0,0 0 0,11 20 023 50 00 0 0,0 0 0,27 7 00 0 0,0 0 0,0 0 0,0 0 0,0 0 0,16 1 00 0 0,
```

Comment: So what do  you actually want to happen to the number? This is pretty unclear

Comment: In my opinion this wasn't that unclear. A little lack of english language no need to mark it as unclear right away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php

$value='1 0 0,4 2 0,1 20 0,3 0 0,2 0 0,2 0 0,3 0 0,4 0 0,4 0 0,3 0 0,3 0 0,4 0 0,4 0 0,1 0 0,4 0 0,2 0 0,1 0 0,2 0 0,0 0 0,0 0 0,0 0 0,0 0 0,0 0 0,0 0 0,10 20 0,15 20 0,0 0 0,0 0 0,11 20 0,23 10 0,0 0 0,0 0 0,27 7 0,0 0 0,0 0 0,0 0 0,0 0 0,0 0 0,16 1 0,0 0 0';
echo $value . '</br>';
$resouces_array=explode(',', $value);

$output = array();

foreach ($resouces_array as $value)
{
    $numbers = explode(' ', $value);

    if($numbers[0] == 23)
    {
        $numbers[1] = 50;
    }

    $output[] = implode(' ', $numbers);

}

$output = implode(',', $output);
echo $output;

?>
```

The problem you had was that you were not properly deconstructing and rebuilding the array of arrays. Above is my answer to your problem a double explode based on a `,` and  then a double implode of those delimiters. In the loop it check the first item of one of the arrays then modifes the 2nd number of the array. You could put this in a near function format to reuse quickly.